# Unable to loop until valid value is entered

Tags: java

I have following code

```
Public class MyClasses implements ForceValidation
{
      Public boolean validateValues(int a){
             If (a==0){
                 System.out.println("it is zero");
                 return false;
               }
              else
                    return true;
         }

   public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner sc=new scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            int a=sc.nextInt();
            MyClasses m=new MyClasses();
            boolean b=true;
            while (b){
                   b=m.validateValues(a);
                   if(b){
                      System.out.println("valid value");
                      break;
                       }
             }
         }
}
```

Though I am getting correct output but here I want to loop until valid value is entered

Please suggest solution

Comment: Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but here I want to loop until valid value is entered

Since you want to continuously receive a value until it is valid. It is an obvious hint you need to enclose your prompting of input ***within*** your loop:

```
System.out.println("enter a number");  
int a=sc.nextInt(); 

while(!validateValue(a)){                   //so long value is invalid, repeat.
    System.out.println("enter a number");  
    a=sc.nextInt();                         //prompt for input
}
System.out.println("valid value");
```

---

But if I were you, I will use a `do-while` loop, so we ***do not*** have to ***prompt*** for input ***twice***.

```
do{                   
    System.out.println("enter a number");  
    a=sc.nextInt();                         
}while(!validateValue(a));
System.out.println("valid value");
```

Answer (score 1):

b should be false, until a valid answer has been given:

```
boolean b=false;
while (!b){
    b=m.validateValues(a);
    if(b){
        System.out.println("valid value");
        break;
    }
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
boolean b=false;
while (!b){
    b=m.validateValues(a);
}
System.out.println("valid value");
```